# WPF SparrowChart Binding issue

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, graphic

I cannot make binding to get data for a SparrowChart control:

```
  <sparrow:SparrowChart>
        <sparrow:SparrowChart.XAxis>
            <sparrow:LinearXAxis/>
        </sparrow:SparrowChart.XAxis>
        <sparrow:SparrowChart.YAxis>
            <sparrow:LinearYAxis/>
        </sparrow:SparrowChart.YAxis>
        <sparrow:LineSeries PointsSource="{Binding PlotValuesList,diagnostics:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" XPath="X" YPath="Y"/>
    </sparrow:SparrowChart>
```

`PlotValuesList` is a List of some objects wich contains `X` and `Y` properties. 
This list is define in the same class where `SparrowChart` control is declared.

In the output of the debug for this control appears:

```
    System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : Created BindingExpression (hash=28447227) for Binding (hash=64529095)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 :   Path: 'PlotValuesList'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=28447227): Default mode resolved to OneWay
System.Windows.Data Warning: 61 : BindingExpression (hash=28447227): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=28447227): Attach to Sparrow.Chart.LineSeries.PointsSource (hash=25485653)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=28447227): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=28447227): Found data context element: LineSeries (hash=25485653) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=28447227): Activate with root item <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 106 : BindingExpression (hash=28447227):   Item at level 0 is null - no accessor
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=28447227): TransferValue - got raw value {DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}
System.Windows.Data Warning: 88 : BindingExpression (hash=28447227): TransferValue - using fallback/default value <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=28447227): TransferValue - using final value <null>
```

And here is the tutprial that I followed: https://sparrowtoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Create%20a%20Basic%20Chart&referringTitle=SparrowChart
So, what is worng, because the chart does not appear even if I gave some data.